# Header from react-native-elments not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been playing around with react-native-elements and I can't seem to get the header component to render. I messed around with all the other components in the react-native-elements and they all seem to work.

-- Header doesn't work but a regular text or the search bar works.

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Header
        leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', style: { color: '#fff'} }}
        centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', style: { color: '#fff' } }} 
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', style: { color: '#fff'} }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed,

Try the following code. This worked for me. However, now my issue is that content below header is overlaying on top of it.

```
             <Header
                statusBarProps={{ barStyle: 'light-content' }}
                centerComponent={{ text: 'Dashboard', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
                outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#324C66' }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think color in style it should like this

```
<Header
        leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
        centerComponent={{ text: 'MY TITLE', color:'#fff'}} 
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff'}}
/>
```